# My date-picker is not working

Tags: jquery, css

Following is my code....
Whenever i click on input element then date-picker doesn't display. Where I am going wrong??? Is my css n js are wrong or jquery? Is there any ambiguity between js and css??

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-4">Portfolio Date</label>
<div class="col-sm-3">
@*<input class="input-sm" type="text" id="form-field-4" placeholder=".input-sm" />*@
<div class="input-group">
@*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.portfolioProjectDate, 
new {@class="form-control", type="text",  placeholder="Portfolio Date", required="required" })*@
<input type='text' id="fiscalYear" name="FiscalYear"  class="form-control" placeholder="Booking Date" />
@*<input id="fiscalYear" name="FiscalYear" type="text" value="6/30/2015 7:12:21 AM">*@

<span class="input-group-addon">
<span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
</span>
</div>
@*<div class="space-2"></div>
<div class="help-block" id="input-size-slider"></div>*@
</div>
</div>
<script>
   $(function () {
      alert("O");
      $("#fiscalYear").datepicker(
      {
         dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
         showOtherMonths: true,
         selectOtherMonths: true,
         autoclose: true,
         changeMonth: true,
         changeYear: true,
         //gotoCurrent: true,
       });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Filtered out the @* segments, the templating system what ur using, and tested it here: https://jsfiddle.net/g4upm0hb/ seems to work fine

Comment: could you please respond to the answer so that i can know it is working for you.

Comment: Improve code formatting

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing `datepicker` inside `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fiscalYear').datepicker();
})
```

Be careful that you have included the `datepicker` library and css,

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>  
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

If your `datepicker` works by this then customize it by your configurations,

```
 $("#fiscalYear").datepicker(

            {
                dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
                showOtherMonths: true,
                selectOtherMonths: true,
                autoclose: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                //gotoCurrent: true,
            });
```